# create-react-app "Failed to compile" on start up

Tags: reactjs, npm, create-react-app

I am getting the following error when using `npm` start to open create-react-app.
I'm new to React and I have had no problems the past few days doing the command line to make a new app.

I have tried `npx` start, `npm` start and installed `npm` again for the updated version.

```
Failed to compile
./src/index.css (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-3-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./src/index.css)
BrowserslistError: Unknown browser query `android all`. Maybe you are using old Browserslist or made typo in query.
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at Array.some (<anonymous>)
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
```

Comment: That message is telling your that your CSS is failing to compile. Take a look at your index.css and see what is wrong with it.

Comment: I just installed a fresh create-react-app and I am getting the same error..

Answer (score 35, accepted):

It is a new bug in BrowserList.

There are new reports on this both in create-react-app:
https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/7239

and in browserlist:
https://github.com/browserslist/browserslist/issues/382#issuecomment-502991170

As suggested by John Forbes below the workaround given on the github issue is to change the browserslist entry in package.json to

```
"browserslist": []
```

This will build and run the project.

Comment: The workaround given on the github issue is to change the browserslist entry in package.json to ```"browserslist": []```

Answer (score 2):

As proper temporal solution till bug fixing:
add to package.json this:

```
  "resolutions": {
    "browserslist": "4.6.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30000974"
  },
```

Comment: is "resolutions" supported by npm ? or just yarn?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment you can try this and wait for further fix

```
"browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [  
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can confirm that forcing a yarn resolution for caniuse-lite@1.0.30000974 fixes the error. It must be an issue with the latest caniuse-lite@1.0.30000975 release.

temporary solution:

In  package.json add

"resolutions": {
    "browserslist": "4.6.2",
    "caniuse-lite": "1.0.30000974"
  },

This method solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

I tried updating the `browserlist` and then did this.

1. Delete this part in `package.json`

```
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [
          ">0.2%",
          "not dead",
          "not op_mini all"
        ],
```

2. And run `npm start`
3. It will ask for yes or no, give yes

Solved!